# Check if the dates are more than 1 year apart

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to check if the total of two dates is more than 1 year or not. Below is the code that I am using but this code accepts 1 year. Which I find it wrong.

```
public bool CheckDate(DateTime Date1, DateTime Date2)
{
    DateTime BaseTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
    TimeSpan span = Date2- Date1;
    int years = (BaseTime + span).Year - 1;

    if (years >= 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Is there a way to make it count as days and considering leap years?

Comment: Can we assume that Date2 is always a point in time later than Date1?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add a year and compare the value, like this.

```
public bool CheckDate(DateTime Date1, DateTime Date2)
{
    return (Date2.AddYears(1) > Date1);
}
```

Comment: If we assume that Date2 is always a point in time later than Date1 I fail to see how this could give a correct result when the difference is below 1 year. For example this code for _Date1=01/01/2021, Date2=01/02/2021_ returns true

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) for this kind of date calculations. Also, you can benefit from NodaTime's period feature (that will take care of leap years as well) to find a period between two dates. Folowing is an example similar to your function that you can have a look at and you can read further about date time arithmetics [here](https://nodatime.org/1.1.x/userguide/arithmetic).

```
    private static bool CheckDate(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
    {
        var localDate1 = new LocalDate(date1.Year, date1.Month, date1.Day);
        var localDate2 = new LocalDate(date2.Year, date2.Month, date2.Day);

        var period = Period.Between(localDate1, localDate2, PeriodUnits.Days | PeriodUnits.Years);

        Console.WriteLine("Years: {0} & Days: {1}", period.Years, period.Days);

        if (period.Years >= 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this be a good answer?

```
public bool CheckDate(DateTime Date1, DateTime Date2)
{
  double Days = (Date2- Date1).TotalDays;
  if (Days > 365)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: No, doesn't work for leap years